# Enviar campos dinamicos con ajax con serialize() y agregar a base de datos con Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, serialización

Soy novato en Javascript y Laravel. Estoy intentando crear un formulario de carga de artículos para factura. El mismo permite agregar o eliminar filas a medida que se van cargando los productos y les genera un incremental (1,2,3,4,.. al lado del id en cada campo).

```
<table class="table table-hover text-nowrap" id="productosfactura">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>N</th>
                                    <th>COD</th>
                                    <th>ARTICULO</th>
                                    <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
                                    <th>CANTIDAD</th>
                                    <th>PRECIO</th>
                                    <th>DTO</th>
                                    <th>SUBTOTAL</th>
                                    <th>IVA %</th>
                                    <th>IVA21</th>
                                    <th>IVA105</th>

                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                <tr id="filaproductoagregado">
                                    <td id="nroproducto">1</td>
                                    <td><input  id="busquedaproducto1" name="busquedaproducto[]" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Busca por cod o descripcion" required></td>
                                    <td><input  id="articuloproducto1" name="articuloproducto[]" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" readonly required></td>
                                    <td><input  id="descripcionproducto1" name="descripcionproducto[]" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" required></td>
                                    <td><input  id="cantprod1" name="cantprod[]" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" oninput="actualizasubtotal()" required></td>
                                    <td style="display:none;"><input  id="idprod1" name="idprod[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID ..."></td>                                        
                                    <td><input  id="precioprod1" name="precioprod[]" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" oninput="actualizasubtotal()" required></td>
                                    <td><input id="descprod1" name="descprod[]" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" oninput="actualizasubtotal()" value = 0  required></td>
                                    <td id="subtotalarticulo1"></td>
                                    <td id="ivaprod1"></td>
                                    <td id="valorivaprod211"></td>
                                    <td id="valorivaprod1051"></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Luego envío con el siguiente código con serialize()  (quito un poco para que no quede muy largo)

```
jQuery('#ajaxsubmit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('facturacion.store') }}",
        method: 'post',
        dataType:'json',
        data: {
            formcomplete: $('#formcomplete').serialize(), 
            



        },
```

Cuando hago una prueba de carga del formulario, esto es lo que envía (tiene mas campos porque el formulario tiene datos de cliente y de factura pero no es el problema):

```
formcomplete: "_token=7nXrE7lJ0vNSCcVK05dg6HDm4cmm5VfLjtwW5RZM&busquedacliente=Portaa23%20Juan&apellidocliente=Portaa23&idclient=2&nombrecliente=Juan&celularcliente=1515&condivaclient=Responsable%20Inscripto&cuitcliente=20334376040&telefonocliente=8585&mailcliente=as%40as.com&local=1&fechafactura=2020-12-18T12%3A50&tipofactura=A&nrofactura=0001-000000125&cotizaciondolar=85&busquedaproducto%5B%5D=156151651&articuloproducto%5B%5D=KB-100&descripcionproducto%5B%5D=Teclado%20KB-100%20descripcion2&cantprod%5B%5D=10&idprod%5B%5D=6&precioprod%5B%5D=10&descprod%5B%5D=10&busquedaproducto%5B%5D=12312312&articuloproducto%5B%5D=NX-70002&descripcionproducto%5B%5D=Mouse%20Genius%20NX-7000%20negro&cantprod%5B%5D=9&idprod%5B%5D=3&precioprod%5B%5D=9&descprod%5B%5D=9&busquedaproducto%5B%5D=5151894168516851&articuloproducto%5B%5D=Pen%20drive%2032&descripcionproducto%5B%5D=Pen%20drive%2032%20Kingston&cantprod%5B%5D=8&idprod%5B%5D=7&precioprod%5B%5D=8&descprod%5B%5D=8&pincode=2128"
```

Lo que no logro hacer es agregar los valores de idprod, cantprod, precioprod y descprod a mi tabla
"detallefactura" con laravel en mi controlador. Probé hacerlo con $request como con el resto de los campos pero no estoy pudiendo.

¿Podran ayudarme por favor? Puedo agregar mas info de hacer falta, no queria que fuera tan largo el post. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que tienes es debido a un pequeño problema en tu ajax, con esto te debería aparecer en el request:

```
jQuery('#ajaxsubmit').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('facturacion.store') }}",
    method: 'post',
    dataType:'json',
    data: $('#formcomplete').serialize(), //cambia esto
```

y así deberías poder acceder a los atributos mediante `$request->busquedacliente` o
`$request->input['busquedacliente']` si te funciona podrías meterlo en la base de datos mediante el modelo: `Modelo::create($request->all());`

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Ayudaría al OP le indiques que modificaste

Comment: ItsEdgar94 Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Con lo que me pasaste pude solucionar el problema.